# Fill in an input field on your phone by scanning a QR code using built in browser's ability?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, firefox, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I have a **website** and a **text input fields** on a form. I want some of these input fields to be able to be filled out by scanning a QR code. Is it possible to do QR scanning using native browser's api without using any javascript libraries? If not, which JS library would be best suited for this use case?

Clicking on the input field should launch your camera to scan this QR.